# How can I approximate power consumption given the days billed in each month and the number of residents?

Tags: analysis, soft-question

I recently moved into a 6 person house. After handling an issue with utilities, we have received a bill for a ~3.5 month period. Power usage has not been broken down by month. I am trying to calculate a rough approximate of power used for each month.

Initially, I totaled the number of days billed for each month and calculated the days billed per month as a percentage of the total number of days billed. These were multiplied by the known power rate to get an approximate power usage. However, I realized that I did not account for the number of residents in the house per month. For example, during the month of March, only 16 days were billed and there were 2 residents.

I could use a similar method using number of residents rather than days billed, but that wouldn't take into account the number of days billed per month (e.g. only 16 days in March).

I have searched for solutions to similar problems, but I have not found any relevant information. Unfortunately, my math skills are lacking, and I am unsure of how to effectively phrase my queries. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've attached a new table that hopefully illustrates what I am trying to do.

[Approximate Power Usage Per Month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnKh7.png)

Comment: Just tally the total of person-day and then allocate the bill per person-day. If you were there 57 days then you pay for "57 person-days".

Comment: @PC1 Could you expand upon this answer slightly? My current problem is that 2 residents in one month would theoretically consume far less power than 6 residents the next month. Therefore, dividing the total power consumed evenly per day may result in an unfair distribution of power consumed in a month. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: It doesn't matter the breakdown per month, you should not care this. Let's say that each person consumes 1 kWh per day, no matter what. Then if you have a certain number of kWh that you consumed and you just assign it by person-day. It will work regardless of the month allocation. Just do an example to convince yourself.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you mean. I will work it out and update as necessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the base calculation that you used.  That is, you had a bill for $T$ amount, that comprised $D$ days, so the cost per day is

$$\frac{T}{D}.$$

So, you have $D$ days, and each of the daily $\displaystyle \frac{T}{D}$ costs must be apportioned among the tenants.

Assume that people $p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_R$ have been staying, at one time or another during the pertinent $D$ days.

So, you number the days $d_1, d_2, \cdots, d_D.$

On day $d_k ~: k \in \{1,2,\cdots, D\}$ assume (for  example) that people $p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_s$ were present $(s \leq R)$.

Then, on day $d_k$ the cost $\dfrac{T}{D}$ should be shared equally among the $(s)$ people $p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_s,$ which each person paying

$$\frac{T}{D} \times \frac{1}{s}.$$

---

**Shortcoming of the Above Analysis**.

I have been making the simplifying assumption that power usage is approximately equivalent from day to day.  Suppose, for example, that you are living in a desert.  Then, power usage in the summer will be higher, because the air conditioning will always be on.

However, the analysis in the first part of my answer makes no adjustment for this consideration.  Such an adjustment would require the data of how much power was used on each individual day.

---

**Second Shortcoming of the Above Analysis**.

I have assumed that on any given day, the people residing there are getting equal benefit from the power usage.  Suppose, for example that one specific person runs a *computer data mining farm*, which significantly increases the power bill.

Then, all of the people living there on that day are paying a share of the cost for power that only the data miner is benefiting from.  Here, it would be extremely difficult to nail down, on any given day, how much each of that day's residents are benefiting from the power usage.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I will definitely run the numbers using this method. I think the biggest issue I'm facing is that some residents have been living here for nearly 4 months, while some have only been here for less than 2 months. I don't want the people that have been here for less time to pay for power that was consumed in the 2 months prior to their arrival.